# How to Configure Weblogic Embeded Default Cache Server

Tags: caching, weblogic, oracle-coherence

I am confused about weblogic coherence cache.my question is 
does Weblogic coherence have embeded cache server?I mean when Run Weblogic.cmd ,is there any cache server to be starting?if yes how can I find it's configuration?and how to configure that?

now, when I start weblogic.cmd , in the log console I have this :

that means ,a cluster with cluster name  cluster:0xdb5, is starting,I am looking for a way, that allows me to configure a cache  on this cluster.

I also, In weblogic admin console,create a custom coherence cluster and configure it's cache like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/comWh.jpg)

Add this cluster to adminserver and restart weblogic ,but weblogic ignore my custom cache configuration and load cache configuration from coherence-web.jar 
this is adminserver log :

> Started cluster Name=testcoherence
>
> Group{Address=224.12.1.0, Port=12100, TTL=4}
>
> MasterMemberSet(   ThisMember=Member(Id=1, Timestamp=2016-12-27
>   16:26:44.769, Address=xxx, MachineId=xxx,
>   Location=site:,xxx,process:8544,member:AdminServer,
>   Role=WeblogicServer)   OldestMember=Member(Id=1, Timestamp=2016-12-27
>   16:26:44.769, Address=xxx, MachineId=59906,
>   Location=site:,machine:xxx,process:8544,member:AdminServer,
>   Role=WeblogicServer)   ActualMemberSet=MemberSet(Size=1
>       Member(Id=1, Timestamp=2016-12-27 16:26:44.769, Address=xxx, MachineId=xxx,
>   Location=site:,machine:xxx,process:8544,member:AdminServer,
>   Role=WeblogicServer)
>       )   MemberId|ServiceVersion|ServiceJoined|MemberState
>       1|12.1.2|2016-12-27 16:26:44.769|JOINED   RecycleMillis=1200000   RecycleSet=MemberSet(Size=0
>       )   )
>
> TcpRing{Connections=[]} IpMonitor{Addresses=0}
>
> > <>
>
> <> <> <1482843408062>  <2016-12-27 16:26:48.062/8.792
>   Oracle Coherence GE 12.1.2.0.0  (thread=Invocation:Management,
>   member=1): Service Management joined the cluster with senior service
>   member 1>
>
> <>
>
> <> <> <1482843408124>  <2016-12-27 16:26:48.124/8.854
>   Oracle Coherence GE 12.1.2.0.0  (thread=[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread:
>   '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', member=1):
>   Loaded cache configuration from
>   "jar:file:/C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/coherence/lib/coherence-web.jar!/default-session-cache-config.xml">

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been several months since I asked this question.
a few months ago I solved the issue and I want to share the solution.
Weblogic has an embedded cache server and to enable it you should follow this steps :

> 1- create coherence cluster 
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvoHA.jpg)
>
> 2- in servers tap choose your server and then go to coherence tab
>
> 3- now important part,to enable cache you should check these checkboxes(local storage and coherence web local storage)
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQVVs.jpg)
>
> 4-until now cache server is enabled.now if stop and start server again cache server is enabled and cache services are up and ready to use ,the main point here is that configuration for this cache server are loaded from "default-session-cache-config.xml" that is located in "ORACLE_HOME/coherence/lib/coherence-web.jar".

5- to override cache config file , you can create a configuration file with same name (default-session-cache-config.xml) and place this file in the domain classpath , for example : ORACLE_HOME/user_projects/domains/basedomain

I hope this solution help other users.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to configure Coherence in WebLogic you need to :

1. Create new Coherence Cluster ( Environment -> Coherence Clusters )
2. Associate your WebLogic Managed Server with Coherence Cluster ( YourServer -> CoherenceTab )
3. Configure your Coherence Cache ( you need to create coherence-cache-config.xml and pass it as an argument to your Managed Server )

Every step is described in Oracle Coherence manual :

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12211/coherence/coherence-developdeploy.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot,but the problem is,coherence cluster use coherence/lib/coherence-web.jar!/default-session-cache-config.xml for cache configuration and ignore coherence-cache-config.xml,

Comment: can you please explain that does weblogic have embeded cache server for store data?

Answer (score 0):

Something very similar is happening to me. I try to create a configuration cache, and when I put the file in it and click save it updates the name. I didn't quite understand what the solution would be, I created the blank file in my DOMAIN_HOME and it doesn't work for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).